# Django : Get value of each subselect of a SelectDateWidget

Tags: django, widget, django-forms

I have a very specific HTML design for my form, so i needed it to be all written in HTML, and this I don't use the default form renderer.

I have this SelectDateWidget set up in my Django form. Everything works fine except for the SelectDateWidget: if my form is invalid, I gather all the relevant values and repopulate my custom HTML fields. Problem is I cannot seem to get the values for the SelectDateWidget in my template.

I tried things like `form.mydate_day.value`, `form.mydate.day_value`, and so on... but it seems to contain nothing.

Can anyone help me on that matter?
Thanks.

As requested,
The model :

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
  civilite = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name='Civilite',choices=(('Mlle','Mademoiselle'),('M.','Monsieur'),('Mme','Madame')))
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Email', unique=True)
  nom = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Nom')
  prenom = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Prenom')
  ville = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Ville')
  cp = models.CharField(max_length=5,verbose_name='Code Postal',validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\d{5}$')])
  date_naissance = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
  optin = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Optin')
  date_inscription = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The form:

```
class SubscriberForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Subscriber
    widgets = {
      'civilite': forms.RadioSelect(),
      'date_naissance': extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1994,1900,-1)),
    }
```

The view:

```
def index(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SubscriberForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/coreg.html')
    else:
    form = SubscriberForm()
  return render(request,'index.html', {'form':form,'days':range(1,31),'months':range(1,12),'years':range(1994,1900,-1)})
```

The template :

```
    <label class="lbl" for="jour">Date de naissance :</label>
    <div class="select {% if form.date_naissance.errors  %}error{% endif %}"><span>
      <select name="date_naissance_day" id="jour">
        <option value="--">J</option>
        {% for i in days %}
          <option value="{{i}}" {% if form.date_naissance_day.value == i %}selected{% endif %}>{{i}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </span></div>
    <div class="select"><span>
      <select name="date_naissance_month" id="mois">
        <option value="--">M</option>
         {% for i in months %}
          <option value="{{i}}" {% if form.date_naissance_month.value == i %}selected{% endif %}>{{i}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </span></div>
    <div class="select last"><span>
      <select name="date_naissance_year" id="annee">
        <option value="--">A</option>
         {% for i in years %}
          <option value="{{i}}" {% if form.date_naissance_year.value == i %}selected{% endif %}>{{i}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </span></div>
    <br clear="all" />
```

Comment: Ok somehow i can't say "hello" in the beginning of my post, it's being stripped. So : HELLO :)

Comment: How have you implemented the form and how are you displaying it in the template?

Comment: there you are , edited the post

Comment: Nothing? Maybe i can customize the widget like hell in order to make it look the way i want and use it directly?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get it to work?  If so, maybe you can answer your own question and help others, thanks ;)

Comment: Yeh this is annoying me too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use form.data like:

```
{% if form.data.date_naissance_day == i %}selected{% endif %}
```